# Specifying Share Identifier in EventBridge rule for an AWS Batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

I am writing a cloudformation template for an AWS Batch job triggered by an Eventbridge rule. However, I am getting the following error:

shareIdentifier must be specified. (Service: AWSBatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException;

I cannot find any documentation of how to pass a shareIdentifier to my batch job, how can I add it to my eventbridge rule's cloudformation template?

I have tried passing as the Input variable:

```
Input: |
            {
                "shareIdentifier": "mid"
            }
```

this is not picked up, I have also tried passing shareIdentifier/ShareIdentifier directly in the BatchParameters. this was an unrecognised key.

Comment: Have had to use a state machine instead:

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I couldn't crack this, I had to wrap it in a state machine step, and call that from eventbridge instead. This was the logic in the state machine to add the Share Identifier:

```
"States": {
    "Batch SubmitJob": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": <name>,
        "JobDefinition": <Arn>,
        "JobQueue": <QueueName>,
        "ShareIdentifier": <Share>
      },
```

If anyone works out how to do it directly from Eventbridge, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Today the only request parameter keys that are supported by EventBridge input transforms are `containerOverrides`, `dependsOn`, and `parameters`. Supporting a larger set of request parameters is a good ask though, thanks for the feedback!